# How to read cell value as string instead of time format by openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read cell value.
The cell value in Excel file is '35:00'
But when reading the cell value by cell(row, column).value, it returns value is '1900-01-01 11:00:00'
How can I read the cell value as string display in Excel file?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Blame Excel for the braindead way it handles dates and times. Easy enough to convert it to a time value.

Answer (score 0):

A date/time values in Excel are stored as ***ISO 8601 formatted string or as a single number***, see the Openpyxl docs on [datetime](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/datetime.html?highlight=datetime).

In this case '35:00' is interpreted being saved as ISO 8601 and read by Openpyxl as as a Python datetime value so that includes a date and time component; `'1900-01-01 11:00:00'` with 35:00 being equivalent of `1 day and 11 hrs`.
You will need to convert the value to whatever format you require, be that;
'35:00'
'11:00'
or something else.

If you want the value `'35:00'` to be saved and read as is then enter it as a string in Excel. Openpyxl will then read the value as `'35:00'`.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like he's using an older version that doesn't detect times >= 24 hours.